# Python and JDK SSL certificate

Tags: python, keytool

I was wondering if anyone has ever dealt with importing SSL certificate into JAVA using python, like we do using keytool.

A bash script can do but i was just wondering if there is a module that can do more gracefully.

Thanks

Comment: could you elaborate on what do you mean by *"importing SSL certificate into JAVA using python"*? What is the input (is it a file, what its format: pem, der)? What is the output? How do you want to run it (jython, cpython)? `keytool` has many commands. Do you want to reimplement it in Python?

Comment: I am looking at the same scenario. Import a .pem cert into a Java Keystore. With the JDK keytool I would convert a .pem cert to .der format and them import into a JKS file.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [pyjks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyjks/0.1), but I don't know if it can write to JKS key stores or just read them.

Answer (score 0):

I have this small script to import certificates:

```
#!/bin/bash

#set -xeuo pipefail
set -xe

##cert file location
cert_location=/path/to/Certificates
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)

##check if directory exist
if [ -d "$cert_location" ]; then
    echo -e "\033[31;7m Directory $cert_location exists. \e[0m"
else
    echo -e "\033[31;7m Directory $cert_location does NOT exists. \e[0m"
    return 1 2>/dev/null
    exit 1
fi

# define file array
cd $cert_location
files=(*)


# Use for loop iterate through an array
# $f stores current value
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
    ##check fi alias already in use
    echo -e "\033[31;7m Directory Certificate name $f. \e[0m"
    alias_name=$(keytool -list -keystore /u01/jdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass JAVA_PASSWORD | grep $f | awk -F, '{print $1}')
    if [ -z "$alias_name" ]; then
        echo -e "\033[31;7m $f will be installed \e[0m"
        scp -r -i private_key -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' $cert_location/"$f" "${SSH_SOA}":./deploy/"$f"
        echo -e "\033[31;7mLoading the $f file  \e[0m"
        keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias "$f_$TIMESTAMP" -file ./deploy/"$f" -keystore /u01/app/oracle/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/DemoTrust.jks -storepass KEYSTORE_PASSWORD -noprompt | true
        keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias "$f_$TIMESTAMP" -file ./deploy/"$f" -keystore /u01/jdk/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass JAVA_PASSWORD -noprompt | true
        keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias "$f_$TIMESTAMP" -file ./deploy/"$f" -keystore /u01/app/oracle/middleware/wlserver/server/lib/cacerts -storepass JAVA_PASSWORD -noprompt | true
        keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias "$f_$TIMESTAMP" -file ./deploy/"$f" -keystore /u01/data/domains/intsoaol_domain/security/DemoIdentity.jks -storepass JAVA_PASSWORD -noprompt | true
    else
        echo -e "\033[31;7m $alias_name Alias already in use \e[0m"
    fi
done
```